# Java MouseEvent formMouseClicked

Tags: java

```
private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    int flag = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double x1 = 0;
    double y1 = 0;
    while (flag !=2) {
        if (flag == 0) {
            Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            x = location.getX();
            y = location.getY();
            flag = evt.getClickCount();
            System.out.println(flag);
        }
        if (flag == 1) { 
            Point location1 = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            x1 = location1.getX();
            y1 = location1.getY();
            flag = evt.getClickCount();
            System.out.println(flag);
        }

    }
```

Как прочитать два пользовательских клика? Идет зацикливание, ибо программа считает, что всегда сделан только 1 клик

Comment: А что вы хотите получить? Зачем вам цикл while?

Comment: @Arsenicum Нужно получить координаты двух кликов. Цикл нужен был для проверки, сейчас его можно убрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужны координаты двух кликов, то попробуйте следующий код (координаты будут получаться после того как нажали и отпустили кнопку мыши):

```
private void formMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {                                 
    int flag = evt.getClickCount();

    if (flag == 1) {
        System.out.println("Один клик");
        System.out.println("(" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + 
          ", " + 
          MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + ")");
    }

    if (flag == 2) { 
        System.out.println("Два клика");
        System.out.println("(" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + 
          ", " + 
          MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + ")");
    }
}
```

Для получения координат от клика, вам нужно использовать метод mousePressed() (координаты будут получаться после того как нажали кнопку мыши):

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
   Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
   double x = location.getX();
   double y = location.getY();
   System.out.println(x + ":" + y);
}
```

Comment: Работает, но почему он фиксирует только клики с одинаковыми координатами? Те двойной щелчок, а не два щелчка с разными координатами.

Comment: @user192091, вы хотите кликнуть получить координаты, а потом кликнуть в другом месте и получить новые координаты?

Comment: @Arcencum Да, именно

Comment: @user192091, я дополнил ответ, вам нужно использовать mousePressed(). Каждый раз когда вы будете кликать, он будет выдавать вам координаты мыши. Можете конечно и в своём методе formMouseClicked() делать те же действия, и будет работать.

Comment: @Arcencum Спасибо!